# Redux form - how to keep button disabled untill every input is filled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying following react-redux form example:

http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/simple/

It works this way, if user fills at least **one** input, the `submit button` is being enabled.

**I just wonder**, if there's any way to *enable* the button **only if** all inputs were filled?

I don't paste the whole code here, because firstly it's long and secondly it's a live-preview example.

Thank you!

Comment: I struggled with the same issue and finally came out with this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48256410/enabling-submit-button-button-when-all-inputs-is-filled
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a property for that, like `pristine` or `dirty`, but you can use the form reducer. Assuming you are using redux form 6+ something like this should work:

```
connect((state) => {
  return {
    // assuming form is the reducer's name
    myForm: state.form.myForm
  }
})(

    reduxForm({
      form: 'myForm'
    })(({ handleSubmit, myForm }) => {
      // myForm.values contains all fields that have value.
      // myForm.fields contains all fields
      const len = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length;
      const allFilled = len(myForm.values) === len(myForm.fields);
      console.log(allFilled);
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field
            name="text"
            component="input"         
          />
          <Field
            name="bar"
            component="input"          
          />
        </form>
      )
   })
);
```

A little explanation, redux form is backed by redux and keeps all information about your forms in the redux store. You can then connect that information to any component, using the standard `connect` function. 
In this example I'm using the `fields` and `values` property to check if all fields have value.

Comment: Why not? Isn't your problem knowing when all fields are filled? the `allFilled` variable will be true only when that's true, and you can use it do enable/disable a button.